# Which old IEs require a width to enclose floating children?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

We can use `overflow: auto;` to force parents to enclose floating children. Example:

```
<style>
p {
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: auto;
}

img { 
  float: right;
}
</style>

<p>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/125/253" alt="Very Tall Image with Kitten" />
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
</p>
```

For containing floated elements, *Smashing CSS* by Eric Meyer cryptically mentions

> If you want to be sure you sidestep some glitches in older versions of IE, add an explicit `width` to your overflowed element.

Which old-IEs require a width declared on parents in addition to `overflow: auto;` to contain floated elements?

I've tested a [demo](http://cdpn.io/FKEnx) using IE9's emulation of IE7 and IE8, but both of them enclose floated children without a declared width.

Comment: Given that the book was published in 2010, they are probably talking about 6.

Comment: I googled your question : https://www.google.ca/#q=Which+old+IEs+require+a+width+to+enclose+floating+children  and found this : http://gtwebdev.com/workshop/floats/enclosing-floats.php

Comment: @MilchePatern - Nice find; I found nothing like that when I searched here or Google. It says that IE≤6 would need width. Do you know of any tests of this?

Comment: @KatieK: I was able to reproduce the same behavior in IE5 quirks mode on IE10 using your demo; `overflow: auto` by itself does not prevent the float from overflowing the container.

Comment: No knowledge of any further research at the moment, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This might be not exactly what you are looking for but, I had faced similar issue once in IE7

I had below dropdown menu structure. on page load .secNav is hidden and can be shown on hovering over its respective previous anchor i.e "About Us".

```
<ul class="primaryNav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
        <div class="secNav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">some long text goes here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

basic CSS was

```
.primaryNav > li {position:relative}

.secNav{position:absoulte; left:0; top:20px;}
```

only for below IE8 I need to asign "width" to .secNav which will be equal to its biggest 
children anchor

maybe useful else please neglect